# How do I read the viewbox attribute of an SVG in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I have added an SVG to a canvas element. How do I get access to read the viewbox attribute of the SVG?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.id = "svgObjectElement";
img.type = "image/svg+xml";

img.onload = function(){

    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

};

img.src = "mySvg.svg";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The browser will load the SVG and render it as a bitmap.  All you have then is the `Image()` / `HTMLImageElement`.  The actual SVG is gone by that point.

You would need to load the SVG separately. There are various ways to do that, eg. with AJAX, or create an `<object>` element in your DOM.

Comment: Thank you, I had hoped to add an '<object>' tag to the canvas. @Paul LeBeau